# Displaying an icon on :hover in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a `contenteditable` element that displays an edit icon when hovered with the pointer. I managed that part while the element has content. The element displays `inline`, making it adjust to text contents. The problem is when it becomes empty, in which case I need to change the element's `display` to `block` because I need to set a minimum width, and that can't be done with `inline`. I've also tried setting some padding instead of changing `display` to `block`, but effect was the same.

You can see it in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ecn5f9o/). The element with content works well, but the empty one starts blinking when it's hovered. I want the elements to be editable the way they are, with the text adjusting to contents and breaking words to width, but how can I remove the blinking problem?

Edit: the best behaviour I managed so far was to not include an hover icon when the box is empty, but that's not ideal..

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '[contenteditable=true]:not(:focus):not(:empty)', function(e) {
  icon($(e.currentTarget), '#edit-icon');
});

$(document).on('focus', '[contenteditable=true]', function(e) {
  icon($(e.currentTarget), null);
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '[contenteditable=true]', function(e) {
  icon($(e.currentTarget), null);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your jquery adds the icon, it is appearing inside the content-editable h2, which causes the :empty selector to become invalidated, since you just added the icon to it. This causes the element to move, triggering the mouseout event. And that, is what causes the flickering. Add the icon to the div containing the h2 instead.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '[contenteditable=true]', function(e) {
    icon($(this).parent(), '#edit-icon');
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '[contenteditable=true]', function(e) {
  icon($(this).parent(), null);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0ecn5f9o/1/

Consider using inline-block as well. Also take advantage of the min-width attribute. This example messes with the alignment of the icon you appear to desire, but it does stop the flickering. The icons can be re-positioned to your liking only CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you add the icon you make the element non empty which is creating the issue. An idea of fix it to add the icon to the upper container:

https://jsfiddle.net/0ecn5f9o/3/

```
function icon(el, name) {

  var container = $('.hover-icon', el.parent());

  // Only one icon at a time
  container.remove();

  // Clear
  if (name == null) {
    return null;
  }

  var wrap = $(name, '.icon-set');
  var icon = $('svg, img', wrap).clone();

  // Insert
  container = $('<span class="hover-icon"></span>');
  container.append(icon);

  el.parent().append(container);

  return container;
}

$(document).on('mouseenter', '[contenteditable=true]', function(e) {
    icon($(e.currentTarget), '#edit-icon');
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '[contenteditable=true]', function(e) {
  icon($(e.currentTarget), null);
});
```

Comment: The same as suggested by Doug K, but I can only accept one :) thank you!